# Can I use any other PCIe SSD in Macbook Pro 15 (Retina, Late 2013) with or without adapter?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hard-drive, ssd

I have **Macbook Pro 15 (Retina, Late 2013) ** and want to use any of the following non-expensive but fast and easily available SSD's.

List of SSD's I am looking to purchase.

(1) https://www.ebuyer.com/834850-wd-250gb-black-nvme-m-2-2280-s3-m-pcie-gen3-ssd-wds250g2x0c

(2) https://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsung-V-NAND-Express-Solid-State/dp/B07CGGP7SV/ref=sr_1_6?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1535977412&sr=1-6&keywords=PCIe+SSD

(3) https://www.ebuyer.com/766048-samsung-500gb-960-evo-pcie-ssd-mz-v6e500bw?mkwid=s_dc&pcrid=51482419619&pkw=&pmt=&gclid=CjwKCAjwt7PcBRBbEiwAfwfVGPjL0wJJ6bT9I4jjX6_jq4RaO2xjojSvH6shGjzW0CQ4Lwz-nP8TyBoCQFcQAvD_BwE

1. Is it possible to use any of them with proper adapter?
2. which adapter I will need specifically?
3. If none of the above will work then which one should I buy (Except OWC)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing some research I found out you can use any AHCI SSD as long as you have the right adapter. (I got it working!!)

I bought the following adapter and it supports all of the following SSD's

Link: http://amzn.eu/d/iRiLcXq

Supports Following M.2 (NGFF) PCI-e SSD:

1) Samsung XP941 (MZHPU128HCGM MZHPU256HCGL MZHPU512HCGL)

2) Samsung SM951 PCIE-AHCI (MZHPV128HDGM MZHPV256HDGL MZHPV512HDGL)

3) Kingston SHPM2280P2/ 240G/ 480G

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use any of them with an adapter.

If you specifically do not want the OWC one (you do not say why), you can purchase an Apple original part. That will (ofcourse) work.

Comment: I don't want OWC or Apple original because they are really expensive and other SSD's are almost half the price. I am looking for non-expensive replacement but thank you for the answer.

Comment: Those cheaper drives aren’t the same, and they’re not compatible with your Mac. It won’t work - no adapters or anything exists for using them like the original internal drive. You can box them and connect them externally using a adapter electronics and USB/Thunderbolt - but that’s about it.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks I guess I will go ahead with OWC then.

Answer (score 0):

I have a MBP 12,1 with a 1TB Apple SSD but I'm looking for 2TB.  The guys at MacBank in the UK (https://macbank.co.uk) are testing the Samsung NVMe SSD with an adapter in the next couple of weeks and promised to get back to me with their findings.  Not a cheap solution but possible for under £1000 it would seem.

PS: beware the OWC solution - everyone I've spoken to does not recommend this as a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, i have justed installed a samsung 960 evo nvme into my late 2013 macbook pro 13 inch using a adapter.  I havent had any issues so far.  Just format the drive using disk utility, then install macOS Mojave.